# How to connect Qt Desktop application to mysql database running on AWS or any online mysql database

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I am trying to connect a Qt desktop application to mySql db on AWS or online mysql database hosted on free domain. can somebody point me in the correct direction for the same?

I tried creating account on AWS and create mysql db but connection does not work

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    userName = "sql9298899";
    password = "**********";
    databaseName = "sql9298899";
    hostName = "sql9.freesqldatabase.com";

    //create database connection here
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName(hostName);
    db.setUserName(userName);
    db.setPassword(password);
    db.setDatabaseName(databaseName);

DB.open always returns false with lastError as :
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified QODBC3: Unable to connect
```

Comment: Please note , I am not using sockets to connect to mysql db, I simply tested my app on local mysql database but now trying to look how can i host it on a cloud or a remote machine where the Qt client can connect to DB when deployed on any machine.

Comment: Any error information from [QSqlDatabase::lastError](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#lastError)?

Comment: Ok the lastError is this: I guess i would need a driver for this , 
"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified QODBC3: Unable to connect"

Comment: You probably need to link the database client library too. See: [QSqlDatabase::addDatabase](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase-1)

Comment: even after linking the library , it is showing the same error :(